# Can I amend a commit made with VSCode to GitHub repo?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-amend

I learn Git and Using VSCode and just learn the commit "amend" command and now trying it on origin (GitHub).

I can't find any way to do this. Do I need some external tool to do that I don't see any "push amend" from the Git menu in VSCode

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. "amend" is always a local operation. If you amend an already-pushed commit, you have to force-push the branch (look up problems that this can cause).

Comment: Thanks ok so amend is always against the local repo good to know

Comment: So I must make another Push with the tiny change I forgot

Comment: Yes, amending always works against the local repo and if you amend something, it creates a new commit (replacing the old one), so you have to push again

Comment: I just read [this](https://github.blog/2015-06-08-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git/) that a GitHub can be reverted. What you think about this article is it ok?

Comment: What does "a GitHub can be reverted" – that sentence does not parse. Please be as explicit and specific as possible, use the correct terms and avoid ambiguitees. Efficient communication helps you and others. For the sake of Git commands, "GitHub" is only a remote repository, just like any other remote repository.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You do not push amend to the remote repo.
`git commit --amend` allows you to include all current staged changes to your last commit in the local repo, instead of creating a new commit.

Let say you committed all changes but forgot to include a file **include_me.js**.
You may run `git add include_me.js`, then `git commit --amend` to amend your last commit.

As mentioned by knittl, if you amend an already-pushed commit, you have to force-push the branch. Beware, if anyone has pulled the branch before you force push, they will have to reset their local branch.

Comment: the question was not in the scope of Git CLI but in the light of VSCode UI

Answer (score 73):

You can go to `Commit` -> choose `Commit All(Amend)` or `Commit Staged(Amend)`. Take a look at the picture.

[image]

Comment: After amending an already pushed commit, you'll have to use **force push**. If the option is not available in the "Pull, Push" menu item - Enable "Git: Allow Force Push" in settings (`Ctrl` + `,` and search for "force push").

Comment: This seems to include all projects rather than a specific one. The source control interface in Code really needs some work. I thought I could get by without Gitkraken, but the UI just lacks so much in usability and functionality as well.

Comment: The `"Commit All (Amend)"` option does not seem to exist when you use the "Web IDE" approach in GitHub, i.e. running VS Code right in the browser.